# AngularJS directive to modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to send a value from button data-id to a modal dialog.

I have wrote this :

**Button HTML**

```
<button ui-sref=".modal" btn-attr-click data-id="{{data.nip}}">Simulasi</button>
```

**State angular :**

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router','agGrid','angular.filter','ngAnimate']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        .state('masterpegawai.alltalenta.modal', {
            url: '/modal',
            views:{
                "modal": {
                    templateUrl : 'public/js/modal.html'
                }
            }
         })

}

});
```

**Directive**

```
routerApp.directive('btnAttrClick', function() {
  return {
    controller: 'simulate',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        scope.nip = attr.id;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

**The Modal dialog**

```
<div class="modal-overlay fade">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <h2>Modal</h2>
  This modal has a substate.  <a ui-sref=".substate">{{nip}}</a>
  <div ui-view='modal'></div>
  <a ui-sref="app">{{nip}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The modal does shows up but the value of data-id={{data.nip}}" doesn't shown in modal dialog

Comment: isn't `{{nip}}` should be like `{{data.nip}}`? in modal.

Comment: Not working, i wonder if my directive is wrong ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/), you could simply define the ID as a [state parameter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters) (both query or url params would work for you).

Then you can access all of the state's params using [$stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateparams-1). For this you'll need to define a controller for the **modal** view inside **masterpegawai.alltalenta.modal**.

**The edited state:**

```
.state('masterpegawai.alltalenta.modal', {
  url: '/modal?nip',
    views:{
    "modal": {
      controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.nip = $stateParams.nip;
      }],
      templateUrl : 'public/js/modal.html'
    }
  }
})
```

**The edited button:**

```
<button ui-sref=".modal({nip:data.nip})">Simulasi</button>
```

Notice that there's no need for **btnAttrClick directive** as **nip** is passed through **$stateParams**. Also notice that I've added a controller for the **modal view** just to bind the data (in our case, **nip**) to the **$scope**.

Comment: I did not realize that it can be sent through URL, Thank you very much Mr. Cosmin Ababei

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `scope = true` or `scope = false`

- Scope : False ( Directive uses its parent scope )

Code:

```
routerApp.directive('btnAttrClick', function() {
  return {
    controller: 'simulate',
    scope : false,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        scope.nip = attr.id; // parent scope
      })
    }
  }
})
```

- Scope : True ( Directive gets a new scope )

Code:

```
routerApp.directive('btnAttrClick', function() {
  return {
    controller: 'simulate',
    scope:true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        scope.nip = attr.id; // new scope for new element
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: By default, according to the [directive definition object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object), the scope property is false: **"No scope will be created for the directive. The directive will use its parent's scope."**

Comment: If I tried alert(scope.nip) the result pop up but why {{nip}} has no value in modal.html

Answer (score 0):

u can use angular-ui-bootstarp where we have directives created on bootstrap.

moreover u can also send data in resolves.

e.g.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
```

here u can see that

```
resolve: {
            items: function () {
              return $scope.items;
            }
          }
```

is used to send the data to modal and on ok we get the same data bound to scope.

if u want to have your own directive u can simply create a wrapper over angular-ui-bootstrap-modal. :) 
for more info please have a look here :

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/